# Returning all the combinations of a string using regex

Tags: regular-expressions, strings, string-matching

Is it possible for a regex pattern to **return** all the `2^n` combinations of characters of a string as matches?

For example, if the string is `abcd`,

then the regex should return the matches:

```
a
ab
ac
ad
abc
abd
...
...
(16 matches)
```

I was trying this regex for the string `abcd`:

```
(?:.*?)|(?:.*)|(?:.*)|(?:.*)
```

But this is only returning 5 matches - [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FbjJ43/2)

Also, regex patterns like this are dependent on the length of the string to match.
Is there any universal generic pattern which is independent of the input string?

Comment: Do you mean Perl-style regexes, or regular expressions as used in formal CS? In the former case, a regex always matches a *contiguous* substring; nothing can ever match `ac` in your example.

Comment: Oh then what about the latter case? Also you should write it as an answer maybe?

Comment: If you clarify which you're interested in, I'll definitely post an answer (though tomorrow at this point)

Comment: Well I did not know there was a difference between the ones implemented in programming languages vs the ones used in formal CS. You said that it is not possible to do it with the former. So I guess you could tell how to do it in the latter. Really curious.

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental misconception to your question: Regexes do not *return* patterns; they *match* patterns. If you wish to *generate* strings, then you need an algorithm that does so, not a regex.

Comment: Also, referrent to "Is there any universal generic pattern which is independent of the input string?": There is, for example, the pattern `.*` which matches *any* string of *any* length. (Though you probably already know this since you used it in the regex you refer to in the question.)

Comment: Pattern `a?b?c?d?` will match all the 16 combinations of characters in the `abcd` string. Also you can implement this matching as a simple loop, and it will work in general case you asked about.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I could not explain clearly. By `returning matches`, I meant the matches returned in the `Match information` on the right hand side [here](https://regex101.com/r/FbjJ43/2).